# razor syntax insert C# string value into tags section

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I use razor file and want use C# btnStateTag variable as tag name.
So I use it as @btnStateAttr in HTML part.
But it doesn't work

```
@{
    string btnStateAttr = "";
  if (EditFormParameter.SendingCompleted)
  {
      btnStateAttr = "disabled";
  }
}

  <div class="form-group row my-4">
    <button class="col-sm-3 btn btn-success" @btnStateAttr type="button">Send</button>
  </div>
```

What is wrong here.

I want to add an attribute - disabled.

Comment: How specifically does this fail?  Is there an error?  What is the resulting output?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
<button class="..." disabled="@EditFormParameter.SendingCompleted" type="button">Send</button>
```

No need for the extra variable.

When condition is true razor will generate:

```html
<button class="..." disabled="disabled" type="button">Send</button>
```

and when condition is false it will generate:

```html
<button class="..." type="button">Send</button>
```

Comment: Not all versions of Razor (such as ASP.NET MVC 3's) support rendering boolean expressions as boolean HTML attributes though, but I think every version of Razor for ASP.NET Core does support this though...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to use `@if`:

```
    <div class="form-group row my-4">
    @if(btnStateAttr == "disabled")
    {
        <button class="col-sm-3 btn btn-success" disabled type="button">Send</button>
    }else
    {
        <button class="col-sm-3 btn btn-success" type="button">Send</button>
    }
        
  </div>
```